# AngularJS ng-include: Access Denied

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using AngularJS v.1.4.8.

I am doing an angularJS tutorial and I am struggling with ng-include on a div. The code inside the partial I am trying to include works fine when inside the index.html file, but for some reason when I try to include it the program breaks down - giving me an `Error: Access Denied` message in the console.

The program uses the GitHub API to retrieve users and display their repos in the browser. There are no issues with the API connection and I have not hit the rate limit.

## index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>AngularJS Tutorial</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="main.ctrl.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="MainController">

        <h1>{{message}}</h1>

        <h4>{{error}}</h4>

        <form name="searchUser" ng-submit="search()">
            <input type="search" placeholder="username to find" ng-model="username" />
            <input type="submit" value="Search" />
        </form>

        <div ng-include="'userdetails.html'"></div>

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

## userdetails.html`

```
<div>
    <div>Name: {{user.name}}</div>
    <div>Location: {{user.location}}</div>

    <img ng-src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{{user.gravatar_id}}" title="{{user.name}}" />

    Order:
    <select ng-model="repoSortOrder">
        <option value="+name">Name</option>
        <option value="-stargazers_count">Stars</option>
        <option value="+language">Language</option>
    </select>
</div>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Stars</th>
            <th>Language</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="repo in repos | orderBy:repoSortOrder">
            <td>{{repo.name}}</td>
            <td>{{repo.stargazers_count | number}}</td>
            <td>{{repo.language}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

## main.ctrl.js`

```
angular.module("app").controller("MainController", function($scope, $http){
    $scope.message = "Github Viewer";

    var onUserComplete = function(response){
        $scope.user = response.data;
        $http.get($scope.user.repos_url)
            .then(onRepos, onError);
    };

    var onRepos = function(response){
        $scope.repos = response.data;
    };

    var onError = function(error){
        $scope.error = error.status + ": " + error.statusText + " - " + error.data.message;
    };

    $scope.username = "angular";

    $scope.search = function(){
        $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/"+$scope.username)
            .then(onUserComplete, onError);
    };

    $scope.repoSortOrder = "-stargazers_count"; 

});
```

Comment: Remove all code from userdetails.html and put <div>Hello</div> then see what happens? Still same issue?

Comment: I have already tried that and got the same error.

Comment: It is worth noting that I am running the html locally. Can't see that being the issue, though.

Comment: You actually forget to close link tag.It should be close like:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded WampServer and it works now... Apparently wasn't able to access the files locally but for some reason it works through a server.

Comment: correct, `ngInclude` uses ajax and therefore requires a server to parse the request.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Wasn't sure what the reason was but it makes sense now..

Answer (score 0):

Try using `angular-sanitize.js` with `ng-bind-html` attribute.

- Include the angular-sanitize.js http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/X.X.X/angular-sanitize.js
- Add 'ngSanitize' to you module dependencies
  `var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize']);`
- `<div ng-bind-html="userdetails.html"></div>`